# Passing a query of a different model to a view of a different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a `Location` model and a `Services` model, using the context class for the app I can do a query on the service model in the create method of the location, however how do I access those results in a view that is strongly typed view that is tied to locations?

```
namespace LocationApp.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        public Location()
        {
            this.ServiceAssignments = new HashSet<ServiceAssignment>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignments { get; set;  }
    }
}

namespace LocationApp.Models
{
    public class Service
    {
        public Service()
        {
            this.ServiceAssignments = new HashSet<ServiceAssignment>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignments { get; set; }
    }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    using (var db = new LocationAppContext())
    {
        var serv = (from s in db.Services
                    where s.active == true
                    select s).ToList();

         if (serv.Count > 0)
         {
             return View(serv);
         }
         else
         {
             return View();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you showing in the view ? You want to show a list of Services or List of Locations ?

Comment: The view for create shows a form for creating a new location, I want to add a list of check boxes for every single service. So you can tie specific services to a location.

Comment: See my answer which uses editor templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new ViewModel.

```
public class CreateLocationVM
{
  public string Name { set; get;}
  public List<SelectedService> Services { set; get;}  
  public CreateLocationVM()
  {
     Services=new List<SelectedService>();
  }
}
public class SelectedService
{
  public int ID { set; get;}
  public string Name {set; get;}
  public bool IsSelected { set; get;}
}
```

Now in your **GET** action, you create an object of the viewmodel and fill the `Services` collection property and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateLocationVM();

    //The below code is hardcoded for demo. you mat replace with DB data.
    vm.Services.Add(new SelectedService{ Name = "Test1" , Id=1});
    vm.Services.Add(new SelectedService{ Name = "Test2", Id=2 });

    return View(vm);
}
```

Now Let's create an EditorTemplate. Go to `Views/YourControllerName` and create a folder called "**EditorTemplate**" and create a new view there with the same name as of the property Name(`SelectedService.cshtml`)

Add this code to your new editor template.

```
@model SelectedService
<p>
  <b>@Model.Name</b>   :
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected) <br />
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
</p>
```

Now in your Main View, Call your Editor template using the `EditorFor` Html Helper method.

```
@model CreateLocationVM
<h2>Add Location</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>    
    <div>  
      @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Services)         
    </div>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Now when You Post the Form, Your Model will have the `Services` Collection where the Selected Checkboxes will be having a `True` value for the `IsSelected` Property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateLocationVM model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Check for model.Services collection and Each items
      //  IsSelected property value.
      //Save and Redirect(PRG pattern)
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

You can read from your Viewmodel and create your Entities and set the proper values and save to database.